# How to set AppointmentRequest.UserTimeZoneCode property?

Tags: sdk, timezone, crm, microsoft-dynamics

I've tried to schedule a service appointment and was confused with [UserTimeZoneCode property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.crm.sdk.messages.appointmentrequest.usertimezonecode.aspx) of [AppointmentRequest type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.crm.sdk.messages.appointmentrequest.aspx). According MSDN article this is `int` property.

Unfortunatelly, there are lack of information in [official sample code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.crm.sdk.messages.appointmentrequest.aspx) (just fancy "magic number"):

```cs
// Create the appointment request.
AppointmentRequest appointmentReq = new AppointmentRequest
{
    ...
    // The search window describes the time when the resouce can be scheduled.
    // It must be set.
    SearchWindowStart = DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime(),
    SearchWindowEnd = DateTime.Now.AddDays(7).ToUniversalTime(),
    UserTimeZoneCode = 1
};
```

So, where can I find which code match specific time zone? Is any enum for it anywhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it with this [SDK sample code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh547406.aspx): `SampleCode\CS\BusinessDataModel\BusinessManagement\WorkingWithTimeZones.cs`

This sample shows how to use various SDK messages with time zones.

The list of existed TimeZones could be retrieved from system with `GetAllTimeZonesWithDisplayNameRequest` message.

Also, fall across this enum in previous version of SDK: [TimeZoneCode Class (CrmHelpers)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb887715.aspx).
Keep in mind that it totally mismatch TimeZones in CRM 2011, nevertheless be aware of it.